# How to check applied patches in magento 2

Tags: magento2, patches, security, version

Is there a way in Magento 2 to check the applied patch status?

Just like we can check the patch status in [Magereport](https://www.magereport.com/) in Magento 1?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Check the `composer.lock` file in Magento 2 to see if the latest version of `magento/product-community-edition` is currently installed.

---

#### Security report tools

First of all, let me explain that Magereport, and also Magento's own security scan, work from the "outside". These tools fire requests at your Magento installations just like a browser. The guys that have built these tools have found specific tests to run to see if you have applied certain patches, because these patches should have introduced a change in the code viewable from the outside (certain JS code, post requests + response, file accessibility/availability).

Now there are patches that can't be checked from the outside, simply because nothing that was changed is detectable from the outside. So to see if patches are installed, you should go to your installation's source (FTP, SFTP, SSH, Git...) and check it there.

#### Magento 2 status

Magento 2 doesn't have patches in the form of patch files, but in the form of new application versions. So there is nowhere to check for "applied patch status" because there are no patches.

If security issues have been detected and patched (solved) by Magento, then they will release new versions of each supported Magento 2 version. At the time of writing, versions 2.0.17, 2.1.11 and 2.2.2 are the latest versions (see release notes [2.0.x](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html), [2.1.x](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html) and [2.2.x](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html)).

You should check the `composer.json` file (or `composer.lock` file) in your Magento 2 installation and see which version of the `magento/product-community-edition` (or `magento/product-enterprise-edition`) is in there to see which version is currently installed.

Comment: "Magento 2 doesn't have patches in the form of patch files, but in the form of new application " -

I have seen Magento 2 downloadable patch files. It is there. Please check my answer. But I am not sure about magereport.com or Magento security scan tool.

Comment: Hi Kalyan, these are indeed patches from a while ago. 3 out of 4 of these patches are to patch the updater or some part that would block you from upgrading to a new version. So the actual platform (security) updates and new features are still packed into new versions which you should upgrade through Composer or download as full new release. The 4th patch is a hotfix for the ones that could not wait for the 2.1.7 release... I think that would have been a 1 time action from Magento, they'll never do that again...

Comment: See https://twitter.com/7ochem/status/865176854000533504

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 have this tool which can be installed using composer and lists all of the available patches you can apply: https://devdocs.magento.com/quality-patches/usage.html

Answer (score -1):

[Magereport](https://www.magereport.com/) portal also provide security patches information for Magento 2.

Comment: It doesn't... It can read your M2 version (range), but it still shows all the M1 checks, that will be green of course, because it is not an M1 shop...