# Does Magento 2 have an app/etc/applied.patches.list file like Magento 1

Tags: magento2, patches

Apologies if this is a duplicate.  Searched SO and couldn't see that this has been asked before.

In Magento 1 you have a `app/etc/applied.patches.list` file which is updated when applying security patches.

Does Magento 2 have something similar?

Comment: magento 1 patch list is just a simple script writes patch headline name to the file. in magento 2 i guess you have to manage diff code yourself. the idea was to release new version and new codebase everytime, better than patches mess.

Comment: What is your approach to patching M2?

Comment: I think now Magento use hotfixes. Please check - Security Report Tool in your magento panel and this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194781/how-to-check-applied-patches-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

as per magento 2 documentation, they ask you to configure your own tracking system. 
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

correct way is to immidiate release new version, for example 
`2.3.1` -> patched security bug -> `2.3.2` or `2.3.1.1`

but magento either slow, or not following release rules, or either rely on end user.

obviously if they already released some patches, they must implement some sort of external tracking signature.